# If $f(x,y) = u(x,y)+ iv(x,y)$ and $z = x+iy$ where $dz = dx+idy$, then the total derivative of $f$ wrt $z$

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f(x,y) = u(x,y)+ iv(x,y)$ and $z = x+iy$ where $dz = dx+idy$, then the total derivative of $f$ wrt $z$ is $$\dfrac{df}{dz} = \dfrac{df}{dx}\cdot \dfrac{dx}{dz}+\dfrac{df}{dy} \cdot \dfrac{dy}{dz} =\dfrac{1}{2}(\dfrac{df}{dx}-i\dfrac{df}{dy})$$

The first equality i understand, however how do you get the second equality?

I need to know as I need to find further for $$\dfrac{df}{d\overline{z}}, \dfrac{d\overline{f}}{d\overline{z}}$$

Comment: $x=\frac {z+\overset - {z}} 2$,$y=\frac {z-\overset - {z}} {2i}$

Comment: Oh, so you treat $\overline{z}$ as a constant when you differentiate too? Thanks